# Arithmetic expression in swi-prolog

Tags: prolog, arithmetic-expressions

I have the following prolog program:

```
set_1(2).
p(X) :- set_1(X+1).
```

I'm using SWI-Prolog version 5.10.4 for i386 to run the query p(1) on this program.

The answer is 'false'.

I expect the answer to be 'true', because set_1(X+1) should be grounded as set_1(2) and resolved with the first fact.

Why the answer is false and how can I get 'true' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `X+1` to unify with 2 in your example, you'll need to code this using `is/2`.

By itself `X+1` is a valid Prolog term, but even when `X` is unified with `1`, the term becomes `1+1`, not the `2` you expected.

Try instead:

```
p(X) :- Y is X+1, set_1(Y).
```

**Added:** It's probably worth pointing out that the extreme "laziness" of Prolog in evaluating arithmetic expressions allows us to push down responsibility for evaluation from `p/1` into `set_1/1`, at the expense of having to make that predicate a rule rather than a simple fact.

```
1 ?- [user].
|: set_1(X) :- 2 is X.
|: p(X) :- set_1(X+1).
|: {Ctrl-D}
% user://1 compiled 0.00 sec, 3 clauses
true.

2 ?- p(1).
true.
```

Predicate `is/2` is not the only SWI-Prolog built-in that compels arithmetic expression evaluation.  See [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=arith) for a complete rundown.  In particular predicate `=:=` (with infix notation), comparing whether two expressions have equal evaluations, might be useful in some cases.