# Prolog list splitting

Tags: prolog

I tried this to solve problem of splitting list in lists of length 2^0, 2^2, 2^3 ... 2^n

```
split(L, X) :- split(L, 1, X).

split(X, N, [X]) :-
   length(X, L),
   L < N.

split(L, N, [X|Xs]) :-
   length(X, N),
   M = N * 2,
   append(X, R, L),
   split(R, M, Xs).
```

but I have problem:

> ERROR: Type error: `integer' expected, found`1*2' (a compound)
>   ERROR: In:
>   ERROR:   [12] throw(error(type_error(integer,...),context(...,_9654)))

I'm using SWI-Prolog and have no clue how to fix it. I will really appreciate if you could help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arithmetic expression in swi-prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690788/arithmetic-expression-in-swi-prolog)

Comment: Are you aware that `M = N * 2` does not compute `N * 2` and bind it to `M`? `=/2` is a unification operator which unifies the term `M` with the term `N * 2`. If `N` is bound to 1, and `M` is unbound, then `M` will be bound to the term `1 * 2` as a term (equivalent to `'*'(1,2)`). Look up `is/2`.

Comment: @lurker thank you. it's working now